# how can I use regex with pig to Delimitate the data from a tuple of array

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-pig

Hi I'm using pig to extract data from a array  ! exactly from a tuple ( nom_d_hote) !
the data will be like

```
DCL-GUETTACHE.engtp.dz
DCL-GUETTACHE.engtp.dz
DG-MESLOUB.engtp.dz
DG-MESLOUB.engtp.dz
DG-MESLOUB.engtp.dz
```

that représente Direction-name-engtp.dz and I would like to use regex to extract the name only the name
can you show me a example of how regex work with pig and how can I do this please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the field name is f1 in a relation A,you can extract the Name from f1 in relation A like this.

Get everything (.*) between - and .(escape dot).

```
NAME = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(A.f1,'-(.*)\\.)') as name;
```

Comment: i'm using a table from hcatalog so i'm loading tha data like this :                  A = LOAD 'table' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();                      affter that i want to apply regex for one tuple nom_d_hote the expression will be  ".*-(.*).engtp.dz$" but how can i do regex for only one tuple if i'm using table from hcatalog